# how to move objects away from each other by the same distance?

Tags: mesh, objects, transforms, workflow

I have multiple objects that I want to align them on the Y axis by the same distance.
How to achieve this?
Closest thing I got to it is using the randomize function, but it scatters them at a random distance.
I want to achieve this because I want to add them to asset browser, and be able to see them clearly next to each other.

[image: Objects at world origin]

Comment: Have you tried proportional editing, and moving one object up? Linear falloff.

Comment: this wouldn't work.

Comment: GN ... Add grid object and instance collection on points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about a GN solution?

[image]

Hope it helps.

---

Update:

Here a grid solution:

[image]

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this. are there any prequisites? where to place the geometry node modifier? I tried adding them to a collection and adding the geonode groupe to a subdivided edge and also to all the objects but still nothing.

Comment: My bad. I added the geonode to a cube in the collection without realizing it. works great. thank you.

Comment: While we're at it, would it be possible to align them on a grid composed of two axes? This definitely triggered my interest more in geonodes.

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: Great! thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This was something I came up with quickly on geonodes. Probably not the best solution but it works.
[image]

I added an instance of the objects in the scene and translated them along the x axis using a factor of the index of the object. This should evenly space the objects in the collection and you can adjust the spacing by changing the multiplication value. It will also leave the originals in the arrangement so that you can simultaneously see the whole thing joined together and all the separate objects in a line.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. Could you edit your post and briefly describe your workflow and how it works? Perhaps enumerate the used notes and explain the procedure so the answer can be indexed found by searching.

Answer (score 0):

This is my updated version that separates objects to a grid. Objects need to be added to the collection, and the node group needs to be applied to an object outside of that collection. After this, I make Instances real, delete previous objects, Batch-rename instances to remove ".001" suffix, and clean-up the file.

[image: Grid Object Separator]